# Java Skipping last variable

Tags: java

I have been trying to make a basic calculator that calculates the mean of 9 numbers. The problem is it always skips the last line. 
My code:

```
/* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package avarage.calc;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author taine
 */
public class AvarageCalc {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double num1;
        double num2;
        double num3;
        double num4;
        double num5;
        double num6;
        double num7;
        double num8;
        double num9;
        double num10;
        double ans;
        System.out.print("Enter Number #1:");
        num1 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Number #2:");
        num2 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Number #3:");
        num3 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Number #4:");
        num4 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Number #5:");
        num5 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Number #6:");
        num6 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Number #7:");
        num7 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Number #8:");
        num8 = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Number #9:");
        num9 = input.nextDouble();
        ans = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num8 + num9;
        System.out.println("The Average of the numbers you gave is:" + ans / 9);
    }
}
```

When the program runs:

```
run:
Enter Number #1:20
Enter Number #2:20
Enter Number #3:20
Enter Number #4:20
Enter Number #5:20
Enter Number #6:20
Enter Number #7:20
Enter Number #8:20
Enter Number #9:20
The Average of the numbers you gave is:17.77777777777778
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

Comment: i know there is a variable named "num10" i have tried it with that removed and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your average is incorrect because you are missing num7 in your sum

```
ans = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num8 + num9;
```

should be

```
ans = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8 + num9;
```

Comment: thank you. im just starting Java, so still learning the basics :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You have 10 variables, but you calculate average of 9. Is it what you want? Anyway, @the-tom has showed your mistake. You've forgot about `num7` variable.
2. The less lines of code you have the less possibility to get an error.

Probably will be better to do something like that:

```
double ans = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = 9 //Or some other number
for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++){
    System.out.print("Enter Number #" + i);
    ans += input.nextDouble();
}

System.out.println("The Average of the numbers you gave is:" + ans / x);
```

Now if you need to calculate average of 20 elements, all you need is just set the value of `x` to `20`.